# How to test $scope in an AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs

How do I test the $scope object of my controller?

Am I able to get the actual data that was attached to it?

I have my test set up as shown below, but `myScope` is saying `undefined`.

```
'use strict';

describe('myApp.view1 module', function() {
var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController, jsonHandler;
beforeEach(module('myApp.view1'));


  describe('view1 controller', function(){

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $injector) {
      // Set up the mock http service responses
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      // backend definition common for all tests
      $httpBackend.when('GET', 'view1/quizzes.json')
                  .respond({data: '[XXX,XXX,XXX]'});
      // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
      var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

      var myScope = $rootScope.$new()

      createController = function() {
          return $controller('View1Ctrl', {'$scope' : myScope });
      };
      var controller = createController();

    }));

    it('should get the json files', function(){
       $httpBackend.expectGET('/view1/quizzes.json');
    });

   it('should get the json files', function(){
       expect(myScope).toBe("words");
   });
  });
});
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller('View1Ctrl', [

  '$scope',
  '$http',

  function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('view1/quizzes.json')
    .then(function(res){
      $scope.quizzes = res.data.quizzes
    })
    .then(function(){
      $http.get('view1/questions.json')
      .then(function(res){
        $scope.questions = res.data.questions
      })
      .then(function(){
        $scope.quiz = [ [], [], [], [], [] ]

        _($scope.questions).forEach(function(qu){
          _($scope.quizzes).forEach(function(quiz){
            if (_.includes($scope.quizzes[(quiz.id - 1)].question_ids, qu.id)){
              $scope.quiz[(quiz.id - 1)].push(qu)
            }
          })
        })
      })
      .then(function(){
        // console.log($scope.quiz)
      })
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: Where are you logging the value of `myScope`? Why are you using $injector.get() to get a service that is already injected in the function?

Comment: @JBNizet  I was logging it in another test, it was only a play one though so i didn't add it there. I am using $injector.get() most likely because I'm terribly confused and have no idea what i'm doing. Trying to work it out but the documentation doesn't seem to make sense to me :/

Comment: myScope is a local variable of the function passed to beforeEach. So it's only defined in that function. If you want it defined in the functions passed to it(), then it should be declared at the same level as $httpBackend, $rootScope, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet Awesome! so what I've gotten back doesn't appear to have an custom key-values attached. Does that mean I'll need to mock up the controller's $scope in my test?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. I can't see the code of the controller you're testing, and I can't see anything in your test looking for custom key-values. If you want help on writing a test for a controller, you need to post the controller code (make it minimal), and the test code you tried.

Comment: @JBNizet I added the controller and the test i was using to see what comes back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. First let's start by cleaning up the mess a little. You don't need to use $injector to get access to services, since they can be injected using inject.

You also don't want a single test for a whole module. Your test should just test the controller. I'll show you an example testing just the first interaction with the backend.

```
describe('view1 controller', function() {
  // declare the variables that need to be used in all tests

  // the $scope contains the data and functions we want to test
  var $scope;

  // the $httpBackend service allows mocking the http... backend
  var $httpBackend;

  // the $controller service allows instantiating our controller
  var $controller;

  // load the module containing the component I want to test
  beforeEach(module('myApp.view1'));

  // prepare the tests. Use inject to access the services we need.
  // To avoid a name clash with the variables defined above, we can 
  // enclose the actual service names into underscores
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$httpBackend_, _$controller_) {
    // initialize our variables
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $controller = _$controller_; 

    // create a scope and initialize our $scope variable with it
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  // we need to be able to instantiate our controller in our tests. Let's
  // define a function that does that
  function createController() {

    // we initialize the controller with the scope we have created sooner
    // so, the scope the controller receives as argument is our scope
    // the controller will populate the scope, and we can test it has 
    // populated it correctly
    $controller('View1Ctrl', { $scope: $scope });
  } 

  // now let's write a simple test. The controller, when instantiated,
  // should use $http to load view1/quizzes.json, and, once it gets 
  // the response, it should populate $scope.quizzes with the quizzes 
  // attribute of the JSON received as response
  it('should populate the quizzes from the backend', function() {

    // we first need to tell our fake backend: you should receive a 
    // request, and when you do, you should return this response

    var data = {
      quizzes: ['hello world']
    }; 

    $httpBackend.expectGET('view1/quizzes.json').respond(data);

    // now we will create our controller. The controller should send
    // a http request to get the quizzes. If it indeed does correctly,
    // the fake backend will return the above data **when we tell it to
    // do it**.

    createController();

    // Now, the controller has sent the request. But it hasn't received 
    // the response yet. Let's send the response.
    $httpBackend.flush();

    // now, the controller should have received the response, and should
    // thus have extracted the quizzes from it and populated 
    // $scope.quizzes with them
    expect($scope.quizzes).toEqual(data.quizzes);
  });
});
```

Comment: I also needed to add `$httpBackend.expectGET('view1/questions.json').respond(data);` because without it it was giving me the error `Error: Unexpected request: GET view1/questions.json No more request expected`

Comment: Yes. I just assumed the controller only asked for the quizzes in my example. But you seem to have understood the principles. Congrats.